# to change project title which appears under icon in iphone?

Tags: iphone

hai,
  my project has created using title as sample.i have used icon also.if i run in iphone simulator in normal mode,sample is shown under my project icon.can i change it to "NEWS"?i have to 
convert all code to new project titled as NEWS?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change the "Bundle display name" in the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Click in the menu:

Projet -> Edit Active Target "AppName"

Scroll down to the point "Product Name" change it to NEWS